# AMDGPU: how to disable DPM?

Tags: amd-graphics

There are many posts explaining how to enable the DPM (dynamic power management) feature of AMD GPUs. I need to do some testing and require to disable it but I'm not sure how.

For Radeon driver, I read it is required to modify /etc/default/grub, by setting

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.dpm=1".
```

May sound obvious, but would it be enough for AMDGPU to do something like this?:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amdgpu.dpm=0"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct.

Depending on what you want to test, you can also disable **bapm** for example.

See the full list of boot parameters for amdgpu and their explanation [here](http://www.mikejonesey.co.uk/linux/amdgpu-linux-driver-parameters).

Comment: Cool, thanks and you're welcome! Could you also upvote my answer?